# How to use babel with npm package that will be used by react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs

Trying to do what I thought was a simple thing.

I have a node package that uses advanced js syntax. I want to depend on it in a react project.

So I installed babel packages via `--save-dev`, and added a `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

That was not enough so I added an npm script under `install` to trigger the compilation. Then I had to include the compiled target `lib/index.js` as my entry point via `main`. So in the end my package.json looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "bla",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "babel src --out-dir lib"
  },  
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {},  
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm install` locally on this project, it builds properly. However when react scripts build this (the dep is from github), I get an error: `sh: 1: babel: not found`.

Why is this so difficult? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`sh: 1: babel: not found` is from your shell not finding the babel binary file (normally under ./node_modules/.bin/babel)

You'd want to compile before you publish to npm, so anyone who installs your package has the built files. But, for Github try something like:

`"postinstall": "npx babel src --out-dir lib"`

Comment: What if I'm installing from github?

Comment: then, you'd have to push your built (transpiled) files as part of your package on github. Or you can make your react project an es6 project and use babel to transpile both react code AND your dependency code..

Comment: See update, (notice x in npX ) npx runs the babel cmd in the proper context.

Comment: @jake still no good: ```You have mistakenly installed the `babel` package, which is a no-op in Babel 6.```

Comment: I disagree, you should never push your build code. You have the right idea in the first place, it's just and environment issue (`sh: 1: babel: not found` is from your shell not finding the babel binary)

Answer (score 0):

This hack worked instead of the `postinstall`:

```
...
"preinstall": "npm install --ignore-scripts && babel src --out-dir lib",
...
```

Source: https://github.com/Financial-Times/structured-google-docs-client/commit/891180db742ed00cace0139b201850f79d337098

Also relevant: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10366

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the need here correctly, but could you not just run the `babel` call in `prepare` or `prepublish` scripts? That way only local `npm install` calls would pick that up.

See more about npm scripts lifecycle: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts